# Finding/Removing duplicates in BigData

Tags: mysql, linux, algorithm, redis

I have a set of Files . each File should contain a set of Unique lines among all Files. for example if File i contains line "Line 1" then no other file should have line "Line 1" (also file i should contain 1 entry of "Line 1")

Problem:

I need to remove all the duplicates from these File. However, the total number of lines exceeds billions so I can't really push all the files into memory and delete as I please.

I thought of few solutions:

1- To create a table in DB and use each line as a unique key, then by throwing all the lines into DB we'll remove all the duplicates.

2- Using Redis Set structure instead of DB.

3- To create a file the line as name of the file. Thus once all the files have been created naturally the duplicates will vanish.

However each solution I could think of requires very massive amount of time and resources which I can't afford at the moment.

So my question is:

1- based on above solution, which route seems to be more reliable?

2- Is there a better solution/technologies that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @Ilja I'm not asking for codes. I'm asking for ideas. I've presented 3 solutions that I know that work but `believed` to be costly and I don't know how costly.

Comment: `cat file_1 file_2 ... file_n | sort | uniq`

Comment: Maybe you can hash (md5 for example) each line to reduce memory /space used.

Comment: @LFI this should help to improve, thx

Comment: @j_random_hacker tried something similar ( `cat file1 file2 ...  | sort | uniq --count | grep -v '^ *1 ' ` ) to get all duplicates but I imagine it fails for over 1Billion lines in files (I will try to see what happens though)

Comment: The only part that needs to load a large piece of the data into memory at once is the sorting, and (on Linux at least), `sort` estimates how much memory is available, breaks the input up into chunks of that size, sorts them, and then merges the sorted chunks.  It will take a long time, but it should not run out of memory.

Comment: @j_random_hacker yeah I've been running it for total of 100M lines for the last 30min, it hasn't broke the system yet, but still running. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed split each file by subfiles, with equal hash values, and thereafter compare these subfiles. For example, you have only 2 files, F1 and F2, and you needed delete duplicated. To do this, you needed split each file to N smalles files by following algorithm:

```
int N = 1024; // split huge file to 1024 subfiles; must be 2^n
FILE *f_arr[N];
for(i = 0; i < N; i++) { 
  sprinf(buf, "file.%04u", i);
  f_arr[i] = fopen(buf, "w");
}

while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), in_file)) {
  int hash = hash_func(buf);
  fputs(buf, f_arr[hash & (N - 1)]);
}
```

Since "Line 1" in both files F1 and F2 will have same hash value(for example, 56), during splitting, it goes to subfiles F1.0056 and F2.0056.

Thereafter, you can iterate each pair of subfiles with same number, and remove duplicates.

Comment: very useful info mate, ty